# Is it possible in Python to set up an interrupt on Wifi Connection drop?

Tags: python, embedded-linux

I am using an embedded board. The problem is Wifi Module is on the same Usb bus as my usb pheripheral. The bus is High-Speed and when performing certain task the USB high speed bus simply drops and wifi stops working. My question is can you use Python to setup an interrupt so that if wifi goes down the python script automatically comes into play and does `ifdown` and then `ifup` and finally if that does not help then reboot. I know how to do these function but thats assuming wifi module is working correctly. I have no idea how to setup an interrupt.

Edit I have tested the system for Kernel panic.  That is simply not the case here. The problem is for some unknown reason USB bus is failing to communicate with modules. I dont have a DPI so cant go into serial debug. But it is just a guess that USB bus fails and connection drops.

Comment: You might be running out of power on the USB bus. The bus can supply only a certain amount (usually a max of 0.5A), and if your peripheral and WiFi combined are trying to take more than that the bus will protect itself by disabling things (sorry that's all a bit vague). However you could easily test for that by connecting the WiFi module via a powered USB hub; that'll provide power to the module instead of your embedded board. If the connection isn't dropped when "performing certain tasks" then power supply limiting was the problem.

Comment: @bazza Its not a power supply problem cause I have connected the power supply directly from yhe board 5V to the usb. I guess its something else. It might be Emi or simply that the bus can't handle two 480 M connections.

Comment: oh well. At least it's not that then. I'm afraid I'm out of useful ideas. I don't know exactly how USB devices and busses negotiate power. If it's done as chatter over the bus itself it could be that the USB host is still dropping the connection; it's not necessarily aware that there's power being supplied direct from the board's 5V. Anyone else got more info?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a bash script:

```
while true; do
    ping -q -c 1 8.8.8.8 || (ifdown wlan0; ifup wlan0)
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Doesn't that rather presuppose that the network connection is to the Internet? This won't work if it's a closed network.

Comment: You can ping to whatever address you like to ensure that connection is active. In the closed network it will be most probably the IP of gateway.

Comment: @tomasbedrich I tried a similar script but the board won't respond. I guess a hardware based watchdog is the only solution.